# WPF DataGrid.selectedIndex don't have the full focus on

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, focus, observablecollection

I would like to select automaticaaly my first Item in my data grid ( when my form loaded )

Here is my code

```
myDataGridEvtCode.Focus();
myDataGridEvtCode.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

My problem is that if i use the Arrow ( down ), the row don't change, i need to input 3 times in order to change the selected row. I think it's because my SelectedItem is bad focused.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Datagrid Focus and keyboard focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537073/wpf-datagrid-focus-and-keyboard-focus)

Answer (score 1):

I collected information for DataGrid row keyboard focusing from various resources and finally my solution looks like:

```
public void SelectRow(DataGrid grid, int rowIndex)
    {
        grid.SelectedItem = null;

        object item = grid.Items[rowIndex];

        grid.SelectedItem = item;

        var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
        if (row == null)
        {
            grid.ScrollIntoView(item);
            row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(rowIndex) as DataGridRow;
        }

        if (row != null)
        {
            row.Focus();
            FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(row, true);
            FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(row, row);
        }
    }
```

Also, there is a little bug, with DataGrid keyboard behavior, when we trying to move focus from selected item row to the next row with arrow keys. 
It moves focus to the current row from row container on first key pressing (which is strange, because focus is somehow is not on the selected row item, that was selected in SelectRow method).

I found a solution, and modified it for my purpose.

[Here is](http://cytivrat.blogspot.ru/2011/05/selecting-first-item-in-wpf-listview.html) an explanation, how it's possible to fix this bug.

And based on it, here is my realization:

```
private void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (grid.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
        {
            int index = grid.SelectedIndex;

            if (index >= 0)
            {
                var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as DataGridRow;

                if (row != null)
                {
                    row.Focus();

                    var presenter = FindVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(row);
                    var cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0);
                    cell.Focus();

                    FocusManager.SetIsFocusScope(row, true);
                    FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(cell, cell);
                }

            }
        }
    }

public static TChildItem FindVisualChild<TChildItem>(DependencyObject obj) where TChildItem : DependencyObject
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
            if (child is TChildItem)
                return (TChildItem)child;

            var childOfChild = FindVisualChild<TChildItem>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and subscribe to an event in constructor:

```
grid.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
```

I hope it will help someone to figure out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple types of Focus in WPF, including Logical Focus and Keyboard Focus.  It sounds to me like the selected row is receiving Logical Focus but not Keyboard Focus.  You can set Keyboard Focus with the following:

```
Keyboard.Focus(elementToFocus);
```

However in my experience Focus can get pretty complicated.  It often requires involving the `FocusManager`, particularly in non-trivial scenarios.

I'd recommend [reading up on WPF Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx) and fiddling with the `Keyboard` and `FocusManager` objects until you have it behaving the way you want.

Comment: I tested the solution and it don't function :(

Comment: As I said, Focus in WPF is rarely a simple answer.  There are many factors, particularly when you're dealing with complex controls with deep VisualTrees.  DataGrids are very complex controls, they may try to manage focus in their own way.  Without actual code to debug, any "answer" is a shot in the dark.  But if you read the article I linked to, and do some debugging (e.g. was is the `Keyboard.FocusedElement`?  What happens when you try to change it programmatically? etc.) hopefully you can get the focus to behave the way you want.  Good luck!