# Keyboard focus to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, keyboard, focus

I have a WPF DataGrid and want to set the focus to the first item so that the user can navigate with the keyboard in the list of items, when the dialogue is opened the first time. With datagrid.Focus ( ); I can set the focus to the DataGrid, but this is apparently not the keyboard focus, because when I press the arrow down key, I cannot navigate in the DataGrid. The focus jump to the textbox "Description" but that is not what I want (see picture).

[image]

How can I set the focus and the keyboard focus in a correct way to the DataGrid? Thank for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution. This works for me

```
Keyboard.Focus (GetDataGridCell (dataGridFiles.SelectedCells[0]));

private System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell GetDataGridCell (System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellInfo cellInfo)
{
  var cellContent = cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent (cellInfo.Item);

  if (cellContent != null)
    return ((System.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell) cellContent.Parent);

  return (null);
}
```

Now, I got the right focus and can navigate with keyboard.

Comment: Does not work: there are no selected cells on load.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving keyboard focus manually using [Keyboard.Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboard.focus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) -

```
Keyboard.Focus(dataGrid);
```

Answer (score 0):

A clear way to do this:

```
DataGridCell dgc = DataGridView.FindChildren<DataGridCell>(true).First();
Keyboard.Focus(dgc);
```

Explanation: The method FindChildren will get a IEnumarable, in this case above the T is DataGridCell. The option "true" is used to force the search in Visual Tree view and the ".First()" is from LINQ to get the first result of IEnumerable. So, you'll have the first DataGridCell of datagrid, now u can set the focus.

I lost much time to find this way, I hope it's helpful.

*English isn’t my first language, so please excuse any mistakes.*